# Can I swap harddrives with identical laptop, and different operating systems

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-8, laptop, switching

My laptop had coffee spilled on it. After cleaning it up with alcohol, everything seems to work fine besides for some keys on the keyboard (which was replaced after the spill) The technician in microcenter said the motherboard is corroded and it  will cost $450 to replace it. So heres my question:
If I was to buy a new laptop, same make and model, can I swap the harddrive if they have different operating systems?
I have a Lenovo E540 running Windows 7. I was only able to find Lenovo E540 with Windows8 or 10? Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should work just fine.  It is best if the motherboard and chipset on the new laptop are the same as the old.  I would make sure that before you swap to shut the original computer gracefully if you still can.  Also if there are any updates from Microsoft pending on the old computer, I would try to do them before the change and restart a couple of times before making the swap.

I do this all the time with our office laptops.  They are all the same (this is one of the reasons why we have all the same hardware) and if something happens to one we just issue a replacement machine and put their hard drive in it and they are good to go.  Occasionally there is a notice that pops up for Microsoft office not being happy.  But a quick run through the built in Microsoft Activation usually takes care of that.

Also after the switch if you start to have issues you could probably do a windows reinstall from the recovery partition if there is a recovery partition. Or if the original laptop came with recovery media you should be able to use this normally.

***Standard disclaimer: Make sure you have a current backup of your important data. Before you do the change over... ESPECIALLY if you need to do the windows reinstall.

Good luck!